# If div class contains certain text then adjust css for that class only

Tags: jquery, html, css, contains

I am trying to get this jQuery script to only apply the css to the class which contains the text, and not the others.

If the class contains a certain text, I want to limit the width by 100 pixels, and the height by 100 pixels.

```
if ($('#targetID > div.targetClass:contains("Important Text")') {
        $('targetClass').css("width" , "100px").css("height" , "100px");
}
```

HTML Here:

```
   <div id="targetID">
    <div>
        <div class="targetClass">
            <a href="#">Not important</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="targetClass">
            <a href="#">Not important</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="targetClass">
            <a href="#">Important Text and Other Stuff</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="targetClass">
            <a href="#">Not important</a>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`:contains` is a selector, it doesn't return true/false as you're trying to use it. You can do what you want with:

```
$('#targetID div.targetClass:contains("Important Text")').css({
  "width": "100px",
  "height": "100px"
})
```

```js
$('#targetID div.targetClass:contains("Important Text")').css({
  "width": "100px",
  "height": "100px"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="targetID">
    <div>
        <div class="targetClass">
            <a href="#">Not important</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="targetClass">
            <a href="#">Not important</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="targetClass">
            <a href="#">Important Text and Other Stuff</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="targetClass">
            <a href="#">Not important</a>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: For the life of me this is not working, and can't understand why, but I don't think it's your code rather implementing it on my website. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: You should be able to see the snippet above working so if it's not working on your site are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

A pure JS method seems the most stable:

```
var el = document.getElementById("yourTagId")
if (el.innerHTML.indexOf("Very cool text copy") !== -1) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: The OP is using `:contains` not `.contains()`, and where do you see that either has been deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in one code line,

```
$("#targetID .targetClass:contains('Important Text')").css("width" , "100px").css("height" , "100px");
```